# MATLAB : Instantiate a class from an empty Instance to a 'Blank' Instance

Tags: oop, class, matlab

Why does my Instantiate function not create a 'Blank' instance of That?

I have the following minimal class :

```
classdef That < handle
 properties
  This = ''
 end
 methods
  function Self = That(String)
   if exist('String','var') == 1
    Self.This = String;
   end
  end
  function Self = Instantiate(Self)
   if isempty(Self)
    Self(1,1) = That;
   end
  end
 end
end
```

If I run

```
This = That;
disp(size(This))     % 1x1
disp(isempty(This))  % False
```

and it's all good, I have a 'Blank' instance of the class

If I run

```
TheOther = That.empty;
disp(size(TheOther))     % 0x0
disp(isempty(TheOther))  % True
TheOther.Instantiate;  
disp(size(TheOther))     % 0x0   - Expecting 1x1
disp(isempty(TheOther))  % True  - Expecting False
```

As you can see running my Instantiate doesn't work and I can't see why ? Surely it should replace the empty instance with a non empty, yet blank, one ?

UPDATE :

The Link from SCFrench lead to this http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_oop/brd4btr.html under the heading Creating Empty Arrays, though this didn't work either :

```
function Self = Instantiate(Self)
 if isempty(Self)
  Blank = That;
  Props = properties(Blank)
  for idp = 1:length(Props)
   Self(1,1).(Props{idp}) = Blank.(Props{idp});
  end
 end
end
```

Comment: your choice of variable names is really something :)

Comment: It was a play on this, that and the other, tired of seeing foobar everywhere :D

Comment: IMO concrete examples are always better; something like a `Student` class with a `name` property

Comment: I have done so on the actual code, will do so here aswell next time :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should make it a static function:

```
methods (Static)
    function Self = Instantiate(Self)
        if isempty(Self)
            Self(1,1) = That;
        end
    end
end
```

Then:

```
>> TheOther = That.empty;
>> size(TheOther)
ans =
     0     0
>> isempty(TheOther)
ans =
     1
>> TheOther = That.Instantiate(TheOther);
>> size(TheOther)
ans =
     1     1
>> isempty(TheOther)
ans =
     0
```

Comment: If I have to do that then it's simpler to do TheOther = That. I'm really working with a tree of objects, so I'm really assigning to This.That.TheOther.Another.OrPossiblySomethingElse, and would really like to instantiate, as I find empty bracnches.

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps, but this demo about making a linked list of nodes with handle class instances might give you some ideas: http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_oop/f2-86100.html

Comment: I went with `Parent.Sub = Sub` in the end. thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

MATLAB passes arrays of handle objects (including 1-by-1 "scalar" arrays) *by value*. A handle value is a reference to an object, which can be used to change the state of the object (i.e. its properties), but importantly, it is not the object itself. If you pass an array of handle values to a function or method, a *copy* of the array is actually passed to the function, and modifying the dimensions of the copy has no effect on the original. In fact, when you call

```
TheOther.Instantiate;
```

The instance of `That` that you assigned to `Self(1,1)` gets returned as the output of `Instantiate` and assigned to `ans`.

[This link](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/matlab-vs-other-oo-languages.html#bslvcv1) to a section of MATLAB Object-Oriented Design documentation might also help.

Comment: So then How do I get ans to assign back to the instance of TheOther ? My understanding is that the argument Self that goes into Instantiate should be a reference to the instance of TheOther and I should then surely be able to populate the original instance ? Then I could make the instance non-empty. Iterating through the Props didn't work (Posted above)

Comment: @Carel: you should really rethink your class design, `Instantiate` should not be a member function; maybe a helper function, or a static one like I suggested..

Comment: May I ask what you'd suggest ? Presently I'm considering overriding empty to create an empty set of items and then override isempty to claim they are empty if their values are the default ones.